# How to test Pagination feature using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, gulp-protractor, protractor-net

Please guide me how to navigate through different pages of pagination using Protractor , i followed this blog: http://seleniumhome.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-can-we-automate-pagination-using.html, unfortunately the code is not working. 
Here is the code from my application:

```
<div class="vertical-align">
<ul class="pagination no-margins">
<li class="arrow unavailable" ng-class="{unavailable: currentPage === 0 || pagedRowsTotal.length == 0}">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(0)" ng-bind-html="rsPaginatorText.first">First</a>
</li>
<li class="arrow unavailable" ng-class="{unavailable: currentGroup === 1 || pagedRowsTotal.length == 0}">
<li class="arrow unavailable" ng-class="{unavailable: currentPage === 0 || pagedRowsTotal.length == 0}">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(currentPage - 1)" ng-bind-html="rsPaginatorText.previous">Previous</a>
</li>
<!-- ngRepeat: page in groupArray track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope current" ng-class="{current: page === (currentPage + 1)}" ng-repeat="page in groupArray track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(page-1)">1</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in groupArray track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{current: page === (currentPage + 1)}" ng-repeat="page in groupArray track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(page-1)">2</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in groupArray track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{current: page === (currentPage + 1)}" ng-repeat="page in groupArray track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(page-1)">3</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in groupArray track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{current: page === (currentPage + 1)}" ng-repeat="page in groupArray track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(page-1)">4</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in groupArray track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{current: page === (currentPage + 1)}" ng-repeat="page in groupArray track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(page-1)">5</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in groupArray track by $index -->
<li class="arrow" ng-class="{unavailable: currentPage === pagedRowsTotal.length -1}">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(currentPage + 1)" ng-bind-html="rsPaginatorText.next">Next</a>
</li>
<li class="arrow" ng-class="{unavailable: currentGroup === groupsTotal}">
<li class="arrow" ng-class="{unavailable: currentPage === pagedRowsTotal.length -1}">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="loadPage(pagedRowsTotal.length - 1)" ng-bind-html="rsPaginatorText.last">Last</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is what i tried, but receiving an error:

```
this.getPaginationsize = element.all(by.repeater('page in groupArray track by $index'));

summaryPage.getPaginationsize.getSize().then(function (pagination) {
            if (pagination > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < pagination; i++) {
                    summaryPage.getPaginationsize.get(i).click();
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Pagination not exists');
            }
        });

Failed: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summaryPage.getPaginationsize.getSize()` method will return an Object with height and width of a webelement. Instead you need to use `summaryPage.getPaginationsize.count()` to get the total number of pageSize.

Reference:

`getSize()` : http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getSize
`count()` : http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count

Comment: Sudharsan thanks for letting me know to use count() method, Now the webdriver is navigating to different pages by clicking on pagination, but when it reaches the last page im receiving an error that the element is not visible.