# Pagination in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I need to automate the pagination in my application, the scenario is : 'to count the number of pages and iterate over the all the pages'and 'test number of rows in each page should not exceed 10'

```
<pagination-controls _ngcontent-c22="" autohide="false" class="my-pagination" directionlinks="true" id="allergyPagination" maxsize="5" ng-reflect-id="allergyPagination" ng-reflect-max-size="5" ng-reflect-direction-links="true" ng-reflect-auto-hide="false">
    <pagination-template ng-reflect-id="allergyPagination" ng-reflect-max-size="5">
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><ul class="ngx-pagination" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">

        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><li class="pagination-previous"> 
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><a aria-label="Previous page">
                Previous <span class="show-for-sr">page</span>
            </a>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        </li>

        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><li>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><a>
                <span class="show-for-sr">page </span>
                <span>1</span>
            </a>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        </li><li>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><a>
                <span class="show-for-sr">page </span>
                <span>2</span>
            </a>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        </li><li class="current">
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div>
                <span class="show-for-sr">You're on page </span>
                <span>3</span> 
            </div>
        </li><li>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><a>
                <span class="show-for-sr">page </span>
                <span>4</span>
            </a>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        </li><li>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><a>
                <span class="show-for-sr">page </span>
                <span>5</span>
            </a>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        </li>

        <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><li class="pagination-next">
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><a aria-label="Next page">
                 Next <span class="show-for-sr">page</span>
            </a>
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
        </li>

    </ul>
    </pagination-template>
    </pagination-controls>
```

Help please. I went through this "[How to test Pagination feature using Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183341/how-to-test-pagination-feature-using-protractor)", but i couldn't succeed in implementing in my scenario.

Comment: do you know the exact number of pages you have in your application?

Comment: number of pages is dynamic, each tab has different number of pages.

Comment: in above example 'allergy' tab has 5pages, like wise 'Ab1' tab has 2 pages, 'Bc2' tab has 10pages, 'EF3' tab has 20 pages and so on..